# lxc container has internet access, how to access internet from host

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I have a requirement that networking has to be managed by lxc container, so the Ethernet interface(eth0, which is the source of internet) is assigned to container.

I am able to ping "8.8.8.8" from the container.

To access the internet from host, created veth type network configuration for the container.

lxc.net.3.type = veth

lxc.net.3.flags = up

lxc.net.3.veth.pair = lxc0

lxc.net.3.hwaddr = 4a:49:43:49:79:bf

lxc.net.3.ipv4.address = 192.168.1.1/24 192.168.1.255

then forwarded the packets from eth1 to eth0 and eth0 to eth1 as mentioned in 
https://superuser.com/questions/938805/how-forward-packets-from-network-interface-to-another

but the "ping -I lxc0 8.8.8.8" is not working from the host.

tcpdump on eth1 interface(tcpdump -i eth1) shows that the ping request is received in the container.

tcpdump shows the output as

ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 192.168.1.2(192.168.1.2 is lxc0's ip in host)

eth0 is the default gateway inside the container.

Comment: iptables doesn't route. So whatever you mean by "routed ... using iptables" you'll have to edit your question to clarify what you did (adding missing IPs, routes, iptables rules)

Comment: @A.B edited the question

Comment: There are still missing informations: what is the IP assigned on `host0`? it can't be XX.XX.XX.XX it should be 192.168.1.Y. I'll give clues for you to find the issue else I fear I'll find there are still missing informations: the container has to NAT the host: you need a MASQUERADE rule on the container. the host needs a gateway: its default route must be `via 192.168.0.1` or you get those strange ARPs

Comment: @A.B ip on host0 is 169.254.99.31 and ip for lxc0 is 169.254.99.30, somehow its not taking the 192.168.0.1 for lxc0

i just now tried https://superuser.com/questions/938805/how-forward-packets-from-network-interface-to-another, still it does not work
default route on host is 169.254.99.31

Comment: Well fix your host's host0 to be in the 192.168.0.0/24 range (I don't know what's the problem), and fix the container in LXC by *not* configuring at all lxc0 by the container's OS: LXC already configured it. don't even declare an lxc0 interface. There are too many small issues at once. Try to solve them then rework your question to have all those informations ready

Comment: @A.B edited the question,  ping between host interface(lxc0) and container interface(eth1) is working now